# Multiple join and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have three tables that I'm trying to create a view. The three tables are,

news

```
---------|---------|
newsID   |  title  | 
---------|---------|
  1      |  title1 |
  2      |  title2 |
  3      |  title3 |
---------|---------|
```

comments

```
-----------|----------|-----------|
commentID  |  newsID  |  comment  | 
-----------|----------|-----------|
  1        |     1    |           |   
  2        |     1    |           | 
  3        |     1    |           |
  4        |     1    |           |
  5        |     2    |           |    
-----------|----------|-----------|
```

votes

```
-----------|----------|------|
voteID     |  newsID  | vote |
-----------|----------|------|
  1        |     1    |   5  |
  2        |     2    |   4  |    
  3        |     1    |   5  |
-----------|----------|------|
```

My query is

```
SELECT  news.newsID,  SUM(votes.vote) AS total,COUNT(comments.commentID) AS comment_count 
FROM news
LEFT JOIN votes ON news.newsID = votes.newsID 
LEFT JOIN comments ON news.newsID = comments.newsID
GROUP BY newsID
```

The result of this query

```
-----------|----------|---------------|
newsID     |  total   | comment_count |
-----------|----------|---------------|
  1        |     40   |      8        |
  2        |     4    |      1        |    
  3        |    null  |      0        |
-----------|----------|---------------|
```

But it should be like this

```
-----------|----------|---------------|
newsID     |  total   | comment_count |
-----------|----------|---------------|
  1        |     10   |      4        |
  2        |     4    |      1        |    
  3        |    null  |      0        |
-----------|----------|---------------|
```

I will use this query for creating a view so I can't use subquery. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this query:

```
    SELECT news.newsID, (SELECT SUM(votes.vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.newsID = news.newsID) AS total, (SELECT COUNT(comments.commentID)FROM comments WHERE comments.newsID = news.newsID) AS comment_count
FROM news 
GROUP BY newsID
```